# Changing/customizing Safari's Web Inspector font

Tags: safari, font-size, safari-web-inspector

Is there a way to customize the font size of Safari's Web Inspector? I found these links on the web and have tried them out but don't seem to work:

1. https://gist.github.com/vlazar/1549785
2. http://miekd.com/articles/adding-some-monospace-to-the-safari-web-inspector/

If there's no solution to this problem, I might switch back to Chrome, for they offer even just a zooming feature for their own Web Inspector. Safari's Web Inspector fonts are just too small for me and my eyes suffer because of that.

I'd be happy to hear about workarounds or solutions anyone might have.

Answer (score 6):

At the time this question was asked, it was not easy to change the zoom level.

In recent versions of WebKit, **It's now possible to zoom the Web Inspector interface using ⌘– and ⌘+.** This should be available in all versions of [Safari Technology Preview](https://developer.apple.com/safari/technology-preview/).

It is not possible to change the font face through the user interface, though alternate font faces are used in various localizations.

Answer (score 2):

Although it is very old question, I want to share much simpler alternative.

- Open web inspector
- Open settings of web inspector
  [image]
- Go to 'General' tab
- Here you will see 'Zoom' option. Change it to a value you feel comfortable and all the text including UI buttons are enlarged.
  [image]

Comment: I use my PC as my primary computer with an Mac Mini on the side. I don't have a Mac keyboard (no real use) so having the GUI option was nice. ︀

Answer (score 0):

The articles you linked refer to an earlier version of Safari. For version 6, the CSS is in a different location, depending on your OS version.

For 10.7.x:

/System/Library/StagedFrameworks/Safari/WebInspector.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/Main.css

For 10.8.x:

/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebInspector.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/Main.css

You will need to chmod the file to edit it (back it up first) and it is compressed so using a tool that can prettify CSS is a good idea (I used WebStorm).

That's as far as I've got, I haven't identified the main content area font size class within the file yet. I'll let you know if I do (or maybe someone else will chime in).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing a search/replace in the Main.css for 'font-size:11px' up to 14px.